# When class is instantiated by Unit Test, System.IO exception is triggered for image in instantiated class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I have a windows form application that is working without errors (compilation creates .exe in bin\debug along with a folder called 'Images'.  This 'Images' folder is in my project solution folder and is set to "always copy".

When the code is compiled, all is well and there are no System.IO exceptions.

However, if that class that refers to the images is instantiated without compiling and through a unit test harness, I see the following:

System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename)
   at YahtzeeApplication.GameBoard..ctor() in E:\workspaces\visual studio projects\Yahtzee\YahtzeeApplication\YahtzeeApplication\GameBoard.cs:line 124
   at UnitTestProject.GameBoardTest.GameBoardElements() in E:\workspaces\visual studio projects\Yahtzee\YahtzeeApplication\UnitTestProject\GameBoardTest.cs:line 37
Result Message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Images\1.dice.GIF

Here is the code that loads the image:

```
diceImageArray[0] = Image.FromFile("Images\\1.dice.GIF");
```

I was seeing if the test class or the instantiated class was not seeing the images. but when I put a folder called 'Images' in either location relative to call the error didn't go away.

What do you do for this scenario in Unit testing?

Comment: I understand that you probably spent significant amount of time to research and pick between embedding files and keeping them separate and then decided on approach you have... But since it is unlikely you'd be willing to mock your image loading manager I'd recommend give embedding images a second though.

Comment: Can you post the code that attempts to find and load the image? Is it in your test code or in the system you are testing?

Comment: @Charlie - I edited the question so the code is now in the question and not just the exception I am seeing.  Right now to get around the error, I am not using images and moving to changing the colour of the picturebox that contains the image.

So again, this code works both when I compile and run the application as the .exe sees that folder and can use the images.  However, when I instantiate that class with a unit test (not compiled), the relative path is not correct.  I believe this is the issue.

Comment: Right now I'm not using the images.  Unit tests are now passing.  Will work on a way to have them embedded, rather than displayed/viewed through code.  The issue I have having right now is that it is not 1-to-1.  It would be very easy to put 1 image on on picturebox.  I am doing that on other forms as a background image and the unit tests pass as there are no System.IO exceptions.  

The form in question has pictureboxes that displays multiple images.

Comment: You're accessing the real resource/images on the disk. Hence this is not a Unit Test. It is an integration test.

Comment: I'm accessing the images on the disk, but I am not checking for them.  I'm just checking the logic of the methods.  I have now removed the images, the tests are exactly the same and now there are results.  I am going to try what @Charlie has mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative path is incorrect because you have no control over the current directory, which is what the relative path is based on. The same code would also fail, if you simply ran a console application without first changing into the directory that contains the image directory, for example...

```
foo\bar\myprogram.exe
```

In general, the user of a program has control over the current directory. It's bad form for a program to change the current directory or to rely on it being set to any specific location... like the location of the assembly being run.

Alternative ways of locating the image directory depend on whether the path is determined in your test or in the application under test. If it's in the test, then NUnit has `TestContext.TestDirectory`, which is the path to the directory containing the test assembly. If it's in the application itself, then the application needs to be coded in a way to find the images directory relative to some specific location, like the directory containing the main program. If you indicate where this code is located, then I can give a more exact suggestion.

**Update - 22-Jan-2019**

The use of a relative path within your application is a weakness of the application, which will cause it to fail in certain circumstances unless you have **complete control** over the current directory setting whenever the program is run. Running the tests under NUnit is just one such circumstance. IMO, you should change the application so that it finds the images at a path relative to the directory containing the exe and **not** relative to the current directory. This takes a little more code but is better because it's actually what you intend to happen. Your tests are doing you a favor by pointing out this problem!

Here's some code that will locate images (see exception below) relative to the location of assembly that does the loading of the images...

```
string assemblyPath = GetType().Assembly.Location;
string assemblyDir = Path.GetDirectory(assemblyPath);
string imagePath = path.Combine(assemblyDir, "Images\\1.dice.GIF");
diceImageArray[0] = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
```

I spread the code over multiple lines so you can more easily see each step. You can, of course, combine some of them. The code has only been "compiled" in SO, so I'll leave any errors for you to fix. :-)

The exception to the above code is if your code is being shadow-copied. Then you need access to the original location it came from and not the current location. If that happens to be the case, it needs a little more code and I didn't want to overly complicate the example.

If the assembly that loads the images always locates them relative to itself, then your tests should work so long as you make sure the images exist at that location.

Comment: The test class, just like in selenium only has to know where the application under test is, and that is not the problem.  I will look into this some more now, but for now I have removed the images and the application is just using text now.  It doesn't look at good, but it works and my tests pass.

Comment: This code diceImageArray[0] = Image.FromFile("Images\\1.dice.GIF"); lives in my application. The folder/images are copied at compile time to the output folder. When debugging or running the .exe, the application works. if I now instantiate the class that has the images through a test, then it fails. It makes sense to me why it does, and the error says it explicitly... the class being instantiated has the wrong relative path to those images. It (the class) would have to be in/at the same level as images, and it is not

Comment: Where is your test assembly located relative to the exe and the Images directory when you are running tests?

Comment: There are two projects in the solution (UnitTest and Application).  The tests are run from the 'UnitTest' project and call classes in the 'Application' project.  The images exist in the 'Application/images' folder.  The classes that call the images folder in the application, use a path relative to the application, so when it compiles, it works.  When I call the application from the UnitTest project, the class are run from their folder, not the bin/debug folder when run as an .exe.  I see why it is happening, but just can't get the folders right